# Specifying the configuration to be used when running an Aurelia application

Tags: typescript, npm, configuration, aurelia, npm-start

I have created a default Aurelia Typescript application with the `au new` command from the Aurelia CLI.

At the root of the project, one finds a `config` directory containing `environment.json` and `environment.production.json` files. Mine look like this:

**environment.json**

```js
{
  "debug": true,
  "testing": true,
  "stringVal": "Hello World"
}
```

**environment.production.json**

```js
{
  "debug": false,
  "testing": false,
  "stringVal": "Hello Production"
}
```

I would like to be able to use different configurations on different runs when running from the command line. My current app.ts and app.html are as follows:

**app.ts**

```ts
import environment from '../config/environment.json';
export class App {
  public message = environment.stringVal;
}
```

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <h1>${message}</h1>
</template>
```

For good measure, my main.ts file is as follows:

```ts
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';
import environment from '../config/environment.json';
import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia): void {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('resources/index'));

  aurelia.use.developmentLogging(environment.debug ? 'debug' : 'warn');

  if (environment.testing) {
    aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-testing'));
  }

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app')));
}
```

1. Without hard-coding an import of the production file, what code changes need to be made for stringVal to read from environment.production.json (or environment.staging.json, etc.)?
2. What flags need to be passed in to `au run` (or `npm start`) from the command line to specify which configuration to use?

Comment: Configuration values cannot be specified at runtime. If you want to run / serve the application using development environment, you can do **au run --env dev** or **au run**. If you want to switch to using production configuration, you must specify **--env prod**.

Comment: Here you can find [environments](http://aurelia.io/docs/cli/basics#environments).

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity. I'm not trying to replace values in any of my .json configuration files. I only want to know how to make the display different for different configurations.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something that cannot be achieved through configuration files. Unlike C# APIS, where app settings are read at runtime, in aurelia apps, configuration files are picked by the bundler and then bundled. Unpicked files don't get bundled, so they can't be "read".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I believe that the question to #1 should be resolved already with the correct environment parameter passed to your run function. One suggestion I have is to make an `environment.ts` file that handles this for you. For example.

environment.ts

```
import env from '../config/environment.json';

function stringVal() {
    return env.stringVal;
}

export { stringVal }
```

Then in your app.ts you can do

```
import { stringVal } from './environment';
export class App {
  public message = stringVal();
}
```

For the answer to #2 it has been mentioned in the comments to your question but I'll share here as well.
`--env` is what you're looking for
Here are the scripts I use for my Au1 Project

```json
    "scripts": {
        "analyze": "webpack --env production --analyze",
        "build": "webpack --env production",
        "build:dev": "webpack",
        "build:staging": "webpack --env staging",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server"
    },
```

I've got an `environment.staging.json`, `environment.json`, `environment.production.json` in my `config` folder and they all work as expected.

Hope this helps! Good luck